# integer or string key field (in MVC application)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, string, database-design, integer, primary-key

My question comes up developing one of my first c# MVC applications with Entity Framework Code First, but I think it is pretty general.

I saw a lot of examples where a table with countries is defined with an integer countryID as primary key, something like this:

```
public class Country
{
    int CountryID {get;set;}
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(3, ErrorMessage = "Country cannot be over 3 characters")]
    [MinLength(1, ErrorMessage = "Country must be filled")]
    string Code {get;set;}
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(25, ErrorMessage = "Description cannot be over 25 characters")]
    [MinLength(1, ErrorMessage = "Description must be filled")]
    string Description {get;set;}
}
```

But, since the country code will never change, it could be the primary key, something like this:

```
public class Country
{
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(3, ErrorMessage = "Country cannot be over 3 characters")]
    [MinLength(1, ErrorMessage = "Country must be filled")]
    string CountryID {get;set;}
    string Description {get;set;}
}
```

Logically, I think the primary key should be the countrycode, but there might be reasons to never use a string as primary key. (performance?)
Is there a reason, why this is normally not done this way? Will I run into problems later if I do use the code as primary key? The same goes for tables like salesorders, shipment ID's etc, where the identifying column will never change.

Comment: In my opinion it wouldn't be a huge performance hit, if any, to use the country code. But I would probably still choose a dedicated column, that I can fully control, to be the PK (like CountryID).

Comment: You don't need both `Required` and `MinLength(1)` they're both doing the same thing.

Comment: Is there a rule of thumb how this is done in large enterprise applications?

Answer (score -1):

PK required for Code First migration. Please add [Key] attribute.

Comment: Doesn't the name of the attribute (classname + ID) do this automatically?